# Data Factory does not like A.U.S. Eastern Standard Time

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to use convertTimeZone to get to my local time in Sydney.

Data Factory is happy with with other conversion like

@convertTimeZone(utcnow() , 'UTC' , 'GMT Standard Time')
but when I try for my location
@convertTimeZone(utcnow() , 'UTC' , 'A.U.S. Eastern Standard Time')

I get an error

In the function 'convertTimeZone', the value provided for the time zone id 'A.U.S. Eastern Standard Time' was not valid.

it is in the list here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/ms912391(v=winembedded.11)

Which is provided in the documentation here.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#convertTimeZone

Any ideas ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the description of destinationTimeZone in [convertTimeZone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#convertTimeZone) function:

> The name for the source time zone. For time zone names, see Microsoft
> Time Zone Index Values, but you might have to remove any punctuation
> from the time zone name.

So remove `.` in A.U.S. Eastern Standard Time and then have a try this expression:

```
@convertTimeZone(utcnow() , 'UTC' , 'AUS Eastern Standard Time')
```

> **April 11, 2023:** This format is no more being accepted by Microsoft, the new format is

```
@convertTimeZone(utcnow() , 'UTC' , 'AET')
```